# Is github3py thread-safe?

Tags: python, thread-safety, github3.py

Does anytone knows if github3py is threadsafe.

Specifically:

- GitHub.repository()
- Repository.iter_pulls()
- Repository.branch()
- Repository.create_status()

None of the threads edit the objects, just share the instances and call the methods.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To give you a more thorough answer, Aviv, since you're simply sharing instances and calling methods, then it is absolutely threadsafe. Some of the questions of requests thread-safety are mostly around cookies, their expiration, and their revocation. Cookies aren't used by github3.py to talk to the GitHub API so you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

As said in [github3py's Readme](https://github.com/github3py/github3.py), the `requests` library is used under the hood. More specifically, every object from github3py has a `_session` attribute which is a `requests.Session` object.

In the [requests documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/), thread-safety is listed among the supported features. However, [this issue](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/1871) and [this issue](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/2766) state that under some circumstances, the Session object is not thread-safe. So, be careful! :)